# How to a TFilterComboBox (drop down box) larger?

Tags: delphi

By default, when I click a Delphi TFilterComboBox it will display only 8 items. To access the rest of them, the user has to scroll down which is such a  wast of time. Can I make it display more items (or even all of them)?

---

I have found an answer that says: "If you click the combobox in the resource template editor, you can drag its "opened" frame size to fit more items".
But I don't know what is this "resource template editor".

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you still using a TFilterComboBox? It's a Windows 3.1 compatibility component carried over from Delphi 1. It's been outdated for more than a decade now.

Comment: Hi Ken. This control is not marked as 'obsolete' in Delphi XE manual. Why do you think I should NOT use it?

Comment: Because you find it on the 'Win 3.1' component palette, and because it's a compatibility component that looks like it belongs in Win 3.1. The entire style and functionality is out of place on modern Windows, and there are much better solutions.

Comment: I don't think there is something wrong in letting the user to QUICKLY (one-click) choose which files to display in a FileListBox. It is WAY much better that the multi-click solution that Embarcadero offers now in Delphi XE in 'File Browser'. Please share if you think there is a better solution.

Comment: `TOpenDialog` or `TFileOpenDialog` spring to mind immediately. They're not only up to date in appearance, but also in functionality. I wouldn't use a `TFilterComboBox` for any reason; in fact, one of the first things I do when installing Delphi is to remove the `Delphi 1 Compatibility Components` package (which contains `TFilterComboBox` - that should tell you something right there).

Comment: You cannot just take make needs and twisted in a way that fits your purpose. I need some kind of Windows Explorer clone where the user can select the files right away because it works a lot with files and folders. Using a Open Dialog WON'T DO IT! So, if there is yet another way to get rid of TFilterComboBox please let us know. I still agree with you to replace it with something better if this thing exists in Delphi's component palette.

Comment: There are the Shell components that ship with Delphi (TShellTreeView and TShellListView) which exactly mimic Windows Explorer's tree and list view. See the Demos\DelphWin32\VclWin32\ShellControls folder. I didn't say I wanted to "twist your needs"; I asked you *out of curiosity* why you were using a Win 3.1 control more than a decade after it became obsolete (from an OS perspective - I never said it was deprecated in Delphi). Regardless of my needs, I would never use that old a UI control in a modern application (in fact, my users would shoot me if I did :)).

Comment: But how can you use a modern TShellListView without using the win3.1 TFilterComboBox????????????????? TShellListView does not come with an integrated TFilterComboBox. So there is STILL no solution to your question. One MUST use Win3.1 controls (unless you opt for 3rd party controls - probably)! Please let us know if you know how to actually DO have a clear solution (without using the 'obsolete' TFilterComboBox).

Comment: I haven't used TShellListView in ages, since TOpenDialog suffices. I'll throw together a quick sample of TOpenDialog with user-specified filters sometime today (probably late today) that might give you an idea of how it can work.

Comment: I just realized I can't post a sample for you, as it doesn't answer this question directly. (The sample would have nothing to do with making a TFilterComboBox drop down larger.) If your question was about how to replace TFilterComboBox with an up-to-date alternative, I could. :(

Comment: Hi Ken. Please let us know you alternative for TFilterComboBox. I open a topic as per your request, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956995/updates-for-controls-in-win3-1-palette

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally one would like to use its DropDownCount property to set the maximum number of items visible in the dropdown window. But that seems to be hidden here (i.e. it is protected). I guess one can send it a message directly:

```
SendMessage(FilterComboBox1.Handle, CB_SETMINVISIBLE, 
  WPARAM(YourDropDownCount), 0);
```

Comment: Need to apply a protected hack though. TFilterComboBox does not publish `DropDownCount`.

Comment: I hate such hacks. OK, sending a message can be considered a hack too, but it is "cleaner" then such a hack, IMO.

Comment: Subclassing TFilterComboBox allows you to avoid the protected hack. I think that's how I'd do it.

Comment: If, with subclassing, you mean writing a descendant and publishing the protected property and then installing that new component in the IDE, I wouldn't. I would do that if I'd have more than one. For a one-off situation, I would find it a bit of overkill.

Comment: For a one-off why are you concerned by protected hack?!

Comment: I simply hate to use hacks, if I can avoid them.

Comment: @Rudy You make a big song and dance about keeping all strings in separate source code files but object to deriving a new class from TFilterComboBox. It just goes to show that so much of what we feel strongly about is just habit.

Comment: I don't make a big song and dance about keeping constants in one place, for a `non-trivial` app, to make them editable with ease, but think it is Good Practice. Avoiding hacks is, IMO, another Good Practice. Deriving a new component for a one-off situation is, however, too much.

Comment: @Rudy - I wouldn't consider 'SendMessage' a hack, but AFAICS it won't work. The VCL calls `AdjustDropDown` in `CBN_DROPDOWN` and AdjustDropDown conforms to `DropDownCount`. Do a test first, but I think you'll have to show the 'protected' hack. <g>

Comment: @Rudy: sending a message just to avoid a one-off protected "hack" is, IMO, too much. The VCL is not exactly a shining example of extensibility. Many private members should be protected, and many protected members should be public. Using a protected "hack" for these cases is simple, fast and very clear in intent, much more so than sending a - too many programmers obscure - message. I for one wouldn't call it a hack but making use of the language constructs available to me. Just as I would gladly use an interceptor class to add some "local" code (and avoid having to install a component).

Comment: @Marjan: the message call is a one-liner. Can't beat that. FWIW, TCustomComBox has a DropDownCount that only needs to be published. That is a sign of extensibility. I have no idea why TFilterCombBox doesn't publish it. Probably to remain compatible with the ones used by the OS.

Comment: @Marjan: FWIW, it is a hack, since you must declare a _descendant_ of the component and then _cast_ that component _to the descendant_ to access the property. That is a hack. But let's not go into that, I've had enough discussions about similar techniques in the Emb. forums.

Comment: @Rudy - VCL's default 8 items is completely arbitrary. [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) deafult is 30. An example, In XP, WordPad font combo in the toolbar has 30 items.

Comment: I don't know why the default is 8.

Comment: @Sertac - works fine for me (D2009). But IMHO it should work in most versions. +1 anyway

Comment: @Rudy: Don't worry, my comment wasn't intended to start a discussion, just to offer a different perspective. Whether you call this specific construct a hack or not, it most definitely has its uses... Welcome to StackOverflow by the way. Still active in the forums? Or has activity there declined even further than when I left them over a year ago?

Comment: Interestingly `AdjustDropDown` no longer works (Vista and 7). You won't be able to set 'DropDownCount' on a regular combo when themes are disabled, neither with DropDownCount nor with CB_SETMINVISIBLE (which requires themes).

Comment: Thanks to all for comments. I would like to use a decent solution that does not involves hacking or sending obscure messages. But since Embarcadero made sure that there is no elegant solution must be happy with what I have. Actually, I should say 'thanks God there is at least this hack'! It would have been ugly without ANY hacks (messages included) at all. So thanks Rudy for your solution. Accepted.

Comment: Where is CB_SETMINVISIBLE declared? It is not in Windows unit.

Comment: @Altar - It's in `CommCtrl.pas`

Comment: Thanks daemon x. It works now (Win 7, 32 bits, themes active)