# Updates for controls in Win3.1 palette

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Some people are saying that I **must** update the controls in Win3.1 palette (especially TFilterComboBox) with modern ones. But does Delphi provide such new controls?

I need to create a GUI (somehow similar to Windows Explorer, consisting in a DirectoryListBox, FileListBox and a FilterComboBox) where I allow the user to easily explore for files of a specific type. Since the interface is centered around this Explorer, a TOpenDialog will be like hitting the customer with a hammer in the middle of his head. I need an 'easy to use' solution.

Unfortunately Shell Controls are not stable enough to be used as replacement.

Comment: What thirdparty libs do you already have? Ie DevEx has some shell controls (on "express utilities" page).

Comment: I try to stay away from 3rd party controls. Usually they are sooner or later abandoned so when new versions of Delphi appear (such as Unicode version) they are actually making you work more instead of less. Let's not also forget that for non-profit libraries you MUST purchase the upgrades.

Comment: @Altar: DevEx have been around a long time though, and have repeatedly demonstrated their commitment to Delphi.  They have a reputation for high-quality controls too.  Don't be so quick to dismiss them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In our application we use [`tpShellShock`](http://tpshellshock.sourceforge.net/) which works rather well.  You may need to tweak it a little for Unicode Delphi, but if I recall correctly that was pretty simple to do.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that looks like Lego. <g>

Comment: That's a 6 column semi-submersible platform with a drilling derrick. It's looks somewhat better [without the aliasing](http://www.orcina.com/images/screenshots/OrcaFlex/full.php?file=JacketToSemisub.jpg&short=Semisub+and+fixed+jacket&long=A+cable+catenary+suspended+between+a+semi-submersible+rig+and+fixed+jacket.+Contact+between+the+cable+and+the+fixed+jacket+is+being+modelled+here.).

Comment: I understood it was a drilling derrick. It just looked like Lego, also because of the colours. <g>

Comment: @rudy The colours are authentic. The drilling  derrick is just the small column on deck.

Comment: @David Heffernan: I'm the only computer geek on the family.. ;-)

Comment: Hi David. How do you let the user choose a certain type of file (like *.mp3; *.doc, etc)?

Comment: This dialog is purely for .x files. The list box is linked to the tree view. There is a list view option too. You add controls to the form and then link them together so that they stay in sync

Comment: I have checked the web page for tpShellShock and the project seems pretty much abandoned. They were not updated since 2003.

Comment: @Altar It's simple to bring it up to date. Screenshot above built with d2010.

Answer (score 7):

The Shell Controls that come as a demo with Delphi only have to be installed, and you'll have some nice shell controls. There is, IMO, no big need to get 3rd party components for that.

Look for ShellCtls (or similar, can't check right now) in your demos folder. That Demos folder can be accessed from the Windows Start menu for your version of Delphi.

### Update

They are not in a Demos folder, it is called Samples now. They can be found in Samples\Delphi\VCL\ShellControls. Install vclshlctrls.dproj first and then dclshlctrls.dproj.

Comment: I've never come across those. One wonders why they aren't a full part of the product.

Comment: Aren't they installed by default? See _Samples_ component palette.

Comment: Because then they would have to log in QC, and fix bugs in them. :-) Seriously though, I expect them to get moved off the Samples component palette at some point as they are now considered part of the VCL by many customers.

Comment: @NGLN: Checking... No, not installed in my Delphi XE, and IIRC not in earlier versions either. The vclshlctrls.dproj and .dpk and dclshlctrls.dpk and .dproj are in the Samples\Delphi\VCL\ShellControls directory though. First install the vclshlctrls and then the dclshlctrls.

Comment: @Warren: They are not even **in** the Samples palette. But many seem to use them, indeed. IIRC, John Kaster wrote them.

Comment: Oops, I don't recall ever having installed them... ;)

Comment: But what is a big major blocker for you might not be a major blocker for anybody else. Given infinite time and resources, I'm sure QC should be a graveyard of closed fixed bugs.  Everything that doesn't get into RAID is not so much a "won't fix" as a "waiting for a reason to fix".   Isn't that better really?  Asking for a final decision in a finite time frame is like asking for one more thing that you can then use as ammo for "why delphi sucks, and I just give up!".

Comment: Well, maybe it will be fixed in XE2.  Join the field test and find out. [wink]

Comment: @David, that is one of those topics that are much better discussed in the Embarcadero forums again. There is an extra group for QC.

Comment: @Rudy I deleted my off-topic comments. Maybe I do need to start at Emba forums!!

Comment: @Warren What do you mean by "join the field test". I actually applied to join the 64 bit beta bit wasn't accepted. I had an e-mail from Mike Rozlog from way back when saying he'd make sure I got on the beta program as soon as it started, but I guess he forgot.

Comment: @david email me charanga.geo at yahoo.com and I'll see if I can get you on.

Comment: Hi Rudy. I have tried those controls some while ago under Delphi 7. They had all kind of issues so I switched back to the 'classics'. But you might be right, maybe Embarcadero fixed the bugs.