# SysListView32 like mouse selection rectangle

Tags: delphi, listview, selection, syslistview32

Can I make a mouse selection rectangle in a List View like in a **SysListView32**?
[image]

Is there a way to work with a SysListView32 and use it in Delphi?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set [`LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) style of the list view (only applicable with comctl32.dll version 6.0 (XP) and later):

> [...] This extended style also enables alpha-blended marquee selection on
>   systems where it is supported.

```
uses
  commctrl;
..

ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(ListView1.Handle, LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER);
```

It also works with the `TShellListView` component included as a demo. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956995/updates-for-controls-in-win3-1-palette/6957661#6957661) to find out how to find and install the shell controls.

(PS: Don't forget to set `Multiselect` to true)

Comment: Congrats on reaching the 10K (I missed the exact transition...)

Answer (score 2):

The site appears to be down currently, but there's a Delphi ListView component available for free from [Mustangpeak](http://www.mustangpeak.net/) that has this feature and more that are found in the modern Windows list view.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to find it. May be there are other components with this feature. But I don't know them...

Comment: I cannot install it on Delphi XE... The last DPK is for Delphi 2007. "requires MPCommonLibD11" -> isn't found in Delphi XE.

Comment: MPCommonLibD11 is part of the Mustangpeak common library. It sounds more like you need to install a different DPK first than an incompatibility with XE.